# NSURLConnection didReceiveResponse for wrong connection

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, sdwebimage

I am attempting to diagnose a very serious bug that causes the wrong image to be downloaded and cached in my iOS client for a given URL. I download a grid of thumbnail images, and in some cases the wrong thumbnail image will appear for a grid cell. I am using the popular image framework [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to manage all of my image downloading, caching, etc. The following code snippets are from the SDWebImage library.

I am seeing a callback to

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
```

That contains a response that is not for the URL I requested, but is instead for a different URL. I know this because in the request headers on my (local) server, I have embedded the file name and the ETag in the request headers. I have written the following code to ensure that the request and response match up:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSString *etag = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).allHeaderFields[@"ETag"];
    NSString *s3FileName = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).allHeaderFields[@"file_name"];
    assert([self.request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:s3FileName].location != NSNotFound);

    // proceed with processing
}
```

That assertion is now failing, meaning the filename in the response object does not match the filename in the request.

I also have checked if perhaps there was a bug in the NSURLCache, so I did this:

```
NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:self.request];
NSLog(@"Cached response for %@ is %@", [self.request.URL absoluteString], cachedResponse);
```

The cached response is always null.

On the server, I can see that the client never, in fact, requested the URL prior to receiving a call to didReceiveResponse.

The timing is as follows:

- Client requests http://localhost/1.jpg
- Client requests http://localhost/2.jpg
- Server responds to request for 1.jpg
- didReceiveResponse is called for the request corresponding to 2.jpg, but with the data for 1.jpg. CORRUPTION
- didReceiveResponse is called for the request corresponding to 1.jpg, with the data for 1.jpg.

Client now incorrectly displays same image in two locations.

Here is a screenshot of what the stack looks like at the time I receive a callback to `didReceiveResponse` with data from a different request:

[image]

I have confirmed that the delegate at the `[self.connection start]` matches the delegate at the `didReceiveResponse` time, and that the `NSURLRequest` also matches both at the start and receive response times.

The only thing I can think of is that there is some kind of corruption within the NSURLConnection library. While I realize that NSURLSession is the new Apple-sanctioned library, I am debugging deep in the internals of SDWebImage (literally, [SDWebImageDownloaderOperation](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/SDWebImageDownloaderOperation.m#L214)), and am not in a position to replace this library or its use of NSURLConnection.

This issue has reproed periodically in the past 18 months, but today I was able to get it to repro within a few seconds every time on one of my older/slower test devices, an iPhone 4S, hitting my local test server.

Can anyone explain my situation where NSURLConnection randomly provides the response to a different connection?

Comment: I had this exact issue once, and it turned out to be an issue with my server's load balancer - it was sending responses to the wrong connections. NSURLConnection is battle-tested and reliable; I doubt it's the culprit.

Comment: Hace you checked your test server supports http pipelining? Any updates on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be there are too many connections, limit the quneue,        `_downloadQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 6;`